# Why the return is False in vscode Jupyter by runing “torch.cuda.is_available()”，but is True in other page

Tags: python

Why the return is False in vscode Jupyter by runing“torch.cuda.is_available()”，but is True in other page.Why the return is False in vscode Jupyter by runing“torch.cuda.is_available()”，but is True in other page[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUHSh.png)

please dolve it.Thanks
ThanksThanksThanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the image, you obviously have multiple virtual environments. Do you have any Docker-based environments? Is Jupyter running from Docker? It may be more difficult to make Cuda work in a contained environment. For the other environments, you need to look at the torch packages that are installed there. Torch has packages with and without Cuda support. If it works somewhere on the machine, then your Cuda and graphics drivers must be okay. Hence, it's likely a problem with one of your virtual environments having the incorrect Torch package.

Comment: no Docker.This environment used in two page is based on anaconda(base).Generally, the environment is same in the two pages.Maybe this environment have two “torch” packages.But why  other the return is True, the other is False.